# Maximizing unique pairs including all elements from both lists

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, combinatorics

I have a data.frame with paired elements, both elements in column 1 and column 2 can be repeated. I would like to obtain the maximum number of pairs, having a unique element from each column but having all the elements in column1 and column2 if possible.

```
> col1 = c("A","A","A","B","C","C")
> col2 = c("X","Y","Z","Y","X","Y")
> df = data.frame(col1,col2)
> df
  col1 col2
1    A    X
2    A    Y
3    A    Z
4    B    Y
5    C    X
6    C    Y
```

I can obtain pairs with unique values from one column, but that sometimes will give pairs that do not have all the possible values from the other column.

```
> df2 = df[!duplicated(df$col1),]
> df2
  col1 col2
1    A    X
4    B    Y
5    C    X
```

In this case, X is repeated in col2, and Z is missing.

My expected output in this case would be:

```
  col1 col2
3    A    Z
4    B    Y
5    C    X
```

Is there any way of maximizing the pairs so that each element of both lists is present in the pair list, at least once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach inspired by minimum spanning tree problem:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, FALSE)
MST <- mst(g)

#get leaf nodes
leaves <- which(degree(MST, v=V(MST))==1L, useNames=TRUE)

#get neighbour to each leaf node in a greedy manner starting with leaf nodes with least neighbours
ans <- sapply(adjacent_vertices(MST, sort(leaves)), function(gph) names(gph))

data.table(col1=ifelse(ans %in% df$col1, ans, names(ans)),
    col2=ifelse(ans %in% df$col2, ans, names(ans)))[order(col1)]
```

Approach assumes that there are a lot of connections so that there will be at least one for each node.

To OP, I will be interested to find out the edge cases where this will fail. Please keep me posted.

output:

```
   col1 col2
1:    A    Z
2:    B    Y
3:    C    X
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much! However, the first pair is given inverted, I can manually change it, but I dont know why this is happening.
They are in the correct order in the graph, but when leaf nodes are calculated, the first pair gets switched.

Comment: You can use setNames(ifelse(ans %in% df1$col1, ans, names(ans)),  ifelse(ans %in% df1$col2, ans, names(ans)). Very interesting question. May I know your area and the application?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am working with DNA sequences, I needed to pair them and select pairs of unique sequences using the most number of sequences for each list. I had written a nested loop removing the pair with the least common sequence each time, but this method is much faster. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh if ordering does not matter, there are some even faster methods online.